# Does Qt Linguist offer the ability to add new entries to the editable .ts file?

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I didn't find a way to do this - only to edit the translations to the existing fields.

If there is no way to achieve this - how should this be done (somehow *automatically*, because right now I was manually adding

```
<message>
    <source>x</source>
    <translation>xx</translation>
</message>
```

blocks to my `.ts` file and I assume that's not the correct way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not the correct way :) Use [tr()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#tr) in the code to mark strings for translation.
For example

```
label->setText( tr("Error") );
```

The you run lupdate for your project to extract them to a .ts. See [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/internationalization.html) for more details.
Or do you need to translate strings that are not in the source code?

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a python script to insert new entries
into the .ts file for a homegrown parser using ElementTree.  It doesnt make the code pretty
when it adds it, but I believe it works just fine (so far):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(infile)
doc = tree.getroot()

for e in tree.getiterator()
  if e.tag == "context":
    for child in e.getchildren():
      if child.tag == "name" and child.text == target:
        elem = ET.SubElement(e, "message")
        src = ET.SubElement(elem, "source")
        src.text = newtext
        trans = ET.SubElement(elem, "translation")
        trans.text = "THE_TRANSLATION"

tree.write(outfile)
```

Where infile is the .ts file, outfile may be the same as infile or different.
target is the context you are looking for to add a new message into,
and newtext is of course the new source text.